# How can I fix import error using google colab?

Tags: python, github, video, import

I'm following [this](https://github.com/microsoft/computervision-recipes/blob/master/scenarios/action_recognition/00_webcam.ipynb) guide, but I have a lot of issues already in the INITIALIZATION.

I use Google Colab and I have done the pip install with `pip install git+https://github.com/microsoft/ComputerVision.git@master#egg=utils_cv`

When running the first error is ***ImportError: cannot import name 'Video***'
with the line `from IPython.display import Video`

I have no idea to fix it, some one can help?

Comment: try to add an exclamation mark before pip, for example: !pip install tensorflow.  This will treat that line (here pip install tensorflow) as a command prompt line and not some Python code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried  !pip install IPython  and the system say me "Requirement already satisfied". However I have the same issue with the line "from IPython.display import Video". Can I remove it?